# SQL INNER JOIN duplicates to be remove based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the below two tables:

Table 1

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬───────────────┐
│ account1 │ Fruit_name │ First_harvest │
├──────────┼────────────┼───────────────┤
│      567 │ Apple      │        201805 │
│      432 │ Mango      │        201809 │
│      567 │ Apple      │        201836 │
└──────────┴────────────┴───────────────┘
```

Table 2

```
┌──────────┬─────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│ account1 │ Fruit_name  │ Current_Farm │ Previous_Farm │ FirstHarvest │ LastHarvest │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│      567 │ Apple       │ APFarm       │ AppleYard     │       201801 │      201810 │
│      567 │ Apple       │ APFarm       │ FruitFarm     │       201805 │      201830 │
│      567 │ Apple       │ APFarm       │ FruitMarket   │       201831 │      999999 │
│      567 │ Royal Gala  │ APFarm       │ GrocerWorld   │       201815 │      999999 │
└──────────┴─────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

My code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.account1,a.fruit_name,Max(a.first_harvest) first_harvest,b.current_farm,b.previous_farm,b.firstharvest,b.lastharvest
FROM   fruit_harvest_data a 
  INNER JOIN fruit_farm_data b 
    ON a.account1 = b.account1 
    AND CASE WHEN b.fruit_name = 'Apple'    THEN 'Royal Gala'
            ELSE b.fruit_name END =
                CASE WHEN a.fruit_name = 'Apple' THEN 'Royal gala'
                ELSE a.fruit_name END
    WHERE  a.first_harvest BETWEEN b.firstharvest AND b.lastharvest 
GROUP  BY a.account1,a.fruit_name,b.current_farm,b.previous_farm,b.firstharvest,b.lastharvest 
HAVING Max(a.first_harvest) >= 201801
```

Result:

```
┌──────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│ account1 │ Fruit_name │ First_harvest │ Current_Farm │ Previous_Farm │ FirstHarvest │ LastHarvest │
├──────────┼────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│      567 │ Apple      │        201836 │ APFarm       │ FruitMarket   │       201831 │      999999 │
│      567 │ Royal Gala │        201836 │ APFarm       │ GrocerWorld   │       201815 │      999999 │
└──────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Request:

I get duplicate data due to the way we have this stored. Is there a 
way to only show the result if `account1` has both `Apple` and `Royal Gala` then it should only select `Royal Gala`.

Please note: `account1` eg., 567 can have multiple fruits like `apple`, `roya gal`, `mango`, `orange`. but should only select Royal gala in case if exists in both apple and royal gala.

Comment: So what happens to the other columns? If you exclude the Apple, do you also want to exclude the previous farm, harvest dates for that row?

Comment: How are you choosing which records to ignore?  Why does `account1` only need to return `Royal Gala`?

Comment: @TomC - Yes, Royal Gala takes priority over apple. Basically, Royal Gala is the new name.

Comment: @iamdave It can return every other fruits.Royal gala was taken as an example being a tricky situation.

Comment: @Mike  *Why* does `Royal Gala` take priority?  Which data defines this order of preference?  Remember that we do not know your system, data or objectives.  You need to give us this information to help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think below should work

```
select distinct T.* from 
        (SELECT DISTINCT a.account1,
     case when a.fruit_name='Apple' or a.fruit_name='Royal Gala' then
    'Apple' else a.fruit_name end as fruit_name  ,Max(a.first_harvest) first_harvest,b.current_farm,b.previous_farm,b.firstharvest,b.lastharvest
        FROM   fruit_harvest_data a 
          INNER JOIN fruit_farm_data b 
            ON a.account1 = b.account1 
            AND CASE WHEN b.fruit_name = 'Apple'    THEN 'Royal Gala'
                    ELSE b.fruit_name END =
                        CASE WHEN a.fruit_name = 'Apple' THEN 'Royal gala'
                        ELSE a.fruit_name END
            WHERE  a.first_harvest BETWEEN b.firstharvest AND b.lastharvest 
        GROUP  BY a.account1,a.fruit_name,b.current_farm,b.previous_farm,b.firstharvest,b.lastharvest 
        HAVING Max(a.first_harvest) >= 201801 
    ) as  T
```

Comment: What if I want to insert the result into a table?

Comment: just use insert into tablename col1,col2...coln select from this query result

Comment: @Mike does my answer solve your 1st describe problem

Comment: @Mike if it help please accept or upvote as a SO appreciation

Comment: it has worked for majority of the records, but there are still some duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Still unclear about what you want in your result set - a more complete desired result would help, but to answer the question as to how to do it:

Since you have mentioned that Apple/Gala is an example, I would create a new table to contain these pairs:

```
create table replace_list(oldfruit varchar(20), newfruit varchar(20))
insert replace_list values ('Apple','Royal Gala')
```

Then in your query add this:

```
left join replace_list r on r.oldfruit=b.fruit_name
left join fruit_farm_data n on n.account1=a.account1 and n.fruit_name=newfruit
```

and in your where clause, you will check where either the fruit name does not have a replacement `r.oldfruit is null` or it does have a replacement, but the farm doesnt have that fruit `n.fruit_name is null`

```
where r.oldfruit is null or n.fruit_name is null
```

The rest of the query you can work out for yourself.